# Worksheet.SaveAs("file.csv") works differently in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I have a project written in C# using the `Interop.Excel` functionality. The method `Worksheet.SaveAs("file.csv", ...)` works differently in relation to the .NET Framework the project is built for.

- When compiled for .NET Framework 3.5, the method saves a CSV file using semicolon (`;`) as delimiter (that is what I need).
- When compiled for .NET Framework 4, it uses comma (`,`) as delimiter, without any other changes in the code.

Can anybody explain what is happening?
And how can I force excel to always use a semicolon as delimiter in CSV files, independently of the target .NET Framework?

Comment: You might want to check the list separator value in control panel, regional settings. What is it set to?

Comment: what about an update?

Answer (score 0):

you can set certain regional settings to your instance of Excel like this, to force how it writes CSV:

```
var cI = new CultureInfo(locale);
var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

excel.UseSystemSeparators = false;

excel.ThousandsSeparator = cI.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;
excel.DecimalSeparator = cI.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
```

Comment: do you need a full solution or hints like this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25398948-56bb-4196-be97-db28c2b5abcd/save-excel-file-as-semicolon-delimited-file?forum=vblanguage) Link the "Local" variable works correctly  when you use Workbook.SaveAs but always uses comma as separator when you try to save a specific Worksheet (like Worksheet(2).SaveAs).

So creating a new Workbook and copying the data into it should work:

```
Orig.Sheets(2).Range("A1:Q999").Copy
Set Export = Workbooks.Add
With Export
    .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .SaveAs Filename:=Path & "\Name.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
```